# Затранскрибируйте текст в соответствии с фонетическими произносительными нормами.

Tags: фонетика

"Слёзы людские, о слёзы людские,
Льётесь вы ранней и поздней порой....
Льётесь безвестные, льётесь незримые,
Не истощимые, неисчислимые, -
Льётесь, как льються струи дождевые
В осень глухую, порою ночной".

Comment: [сл΄joзыл΄утск΄иjэ/асл΄joзыл΄утск΄иjэ/л΄joт΄ис΄выранн΄ийипостн΄ийпарой//л΄joт΄ис΄б΄исв΄истные/]

Comment: Для младших классов школы, старших или для вуза?

Comment: для техникума

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы затранскрибируйте, а мы исправим ошибки, если будут. Выполнять задание никто не будет.

Comment: [сл΄oзы л΄утск΄иjь/о  сл΄oзы л΄утск΄иjь/л΄joт΄ьс΄вы ран΄ьй и позн΄ьй парой//л΄joт΄ьс΄ б΄и(с призвуком э)зв΄эсныjь/]

Comment: парой-а-ослабленное, крышечка^

Comment: http://licey.net/russian/phonetics/1_2

.  http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=663125ae-c4bc-459f-adcd-cb0edbdbf2d1